# String With Format returning Pointer Value, not number

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am having an issue where I am trying to take an NSInteger, and place the value into a label.  Here is the code:

```
NSArray *itemList = [cart objectForKey:@"CartItemList"];

NSInteger itemCount;
for(NSDictionary* cartItem in itemList) {

    itemCount += [[cartItem valueForKey:@"Quantity"] integerValue];

}


[totalItems setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",itemCount]];
```

Item list has one item with a Quantity of 4, however, the label is showing the pointer reference number, not the value of 4.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you get if you NSLog each itemCount in turn? i.e. put NSLog(@"%d", itemCount); as the first line of your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSInteger itemCount = 0;
```

You didn't tell it you wanted to start counting from 0 :)

Comment: That was it.  I knew I was missing something simple.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does it help to change the `NSInteger` to `int`

```
itemCount += [[cartItem valueForKey:@"Quantity"] intValue];
```

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef of int or long so that should have no effect (from the docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16 )

Comment: Well you are right. But my answer suggests to change integerValue to intValue. This is because he is trying to format a NSInteger with %d which is for ints. If he wants to format NSInteger its %ld. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSInteger itemCount;
```

with

```
int itemCount;
```

Comment: NSInteger is a typedef of int or long so that should have no effect (from the docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16 )